# Calling COM server, C++ CoCreateInstance throws "No such interface supported", C# works without issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I'm trying to rewrite some code that calls a local COM Server from C# to C++.  The C# code works without issue.  The key part is:

```
Guid lr_FactoryGuid = Guid.Parse("AE7CFA4B-985A-4F76-8CC6-2011649FC8A9");
Guid lr_FactoryClass = Guid.Parse("1CA0D073-4ABB-4D06-B318-BFFDE38E4903");

IntPtr lk_FactoryPtr = new IntPtr();
CoGetClassObject(
    ref lr_FactoryClass, 
    4, 
    new IntPtr(), 
    ref lr_FactoryGuid, 
    out lk_FactoryPtr);

if (lk_FactoryPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    MessageBox.Show("lk_FactoryPtr  == IntPtr.Zero");
    return false;
}
```

I've tried to rewrite this into C++ and I can't get any further than here, the error is give as "No such interface supported":

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromString(L"{1CA0D073-4ABB-4D06-B318-BFFDE38E4903}", &clsid);

CLSID iid;
hr = CLSIDFromString(L"{AE7CFA4B-985A-4F76-8CC6-2011649FC8A9}", &iid);

void* pIFace;
hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, iid, &pIFace);

if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    _com_error err(hr);
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    
    MessageBox(NULL, errMsg, L"SiteKiosk demo", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
}
```

There is a .tlb file that I used to generate the interop DLL for C# and to import into the C++, however it's currently commented out of the C++ in an attempt to keep the code smaller and I still get this error from CoCreateInstance.

The COM application I'm calling is a 32 bit app, so both my C# and C++ clients applications are also 32 bit.  Both of the clients are Windows Console applications.

Is there anything else I need to set/do to get the C++ working?

Comment: The CoGetClassObject() usage is very unusual, normally you'd ask for IID_IClassFactory.  Nothing that CoCreateInstance() can do, so you likewise have to use CoGetClassObject() in the C++ code.

Comment: The suggestion by Hans solved the problem, I used CoGetClassObject and the rest of the code then clicked into place.

Comment: answer yourself then so the question is closed

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by Hans solved the problem, I used CoGetClassObject and the rest of the code then clicked into place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).